# how show and hide div with time and click option to hide included?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with `display: none;` I want to show it then hide it with in `5 seconds` but if in the mean time a user click on the div it should disappear once it clicked. and seem I can't do both time to disappear and click option.

here the code.

```
$('#div').fadeIn();
$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut();
$('#div').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

if I took out `$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut();` it won't disappear until I click.

if I took out `$('#div').click(function(){  $(this).fadeOut(); });` It won't disappear when user click on it.

### additional info

the thing is if I add this `$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut();` before or after the click code. the div will wait 5 sec and the div will be unclickable.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
$('#div').fadeIn();
timerId = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div').fadeOut();
}, 5000);
$('#div').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    clearTimeout(timerId);
});
```